# How to pass generic keyword arguments and values to the update_record() function in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

My application is submitting tiny bits of information from a form element via ajax (onblur) to the controller `my_function`.

**request.vars** are `<Storage {'my_field': 'the submitted data'}>`.

I understand that it is possible to update a record with `db.table(id).update_record(the_field = 'text')` if `the_field` is a field in the table.

But I try to pass the field_name and data to the `update_record()` function:

```
def my_function():
    keys = request.vars.keys()
    field_name = keys[0]                     # -> The field name to be updated
    content_id = int(request.args(0))        # -> The record id to be updated
    db.my_table(content_id).update_record(field_name = request.vars[field_name])
```

Which is not working: `SyntaxError: No fields to update`. It **is** working if I hardcode the `field_name`. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's keyword argument unpacking syntax (i.e., pass the arguments as a dictionary, which will be unpacked into keyword arguments and their values):

```
db.my_table(content_id).update_record(**{field_name: request.vars[field_name]})
```

Actually, the table has a `_filter_fields` method that takes a dictionary-like object and filters it down to only the fields that belong in the table (excluding the `id` field). So, if there are potentially multiple fields to be updated, you can do:

```
db.my_table(content_id).update_record(**db.my_table._filter_fields(request.vars))
```

Comment: Oh wow... Two asterisks can make a difference! Thank you very much - for both solutions!

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into a similar issue, anytime I need to put a array element into a SQL statement it will only work if I convert it into a string first.

`field_name = str(key[0])`